# third level include sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

currently i am trying to show for each user their liked posts and for the posts i want to show the images as url and thumbnailurl using the method you stated above.

I followed the same steps as my previous questions and keep getting Error Cannot read property map.

```
router.get("/likes", auth, (req, res) => {

  let { id } = req.user;
 User.findByPk(id, {
include:[{model:Likes,
include: [
  {
    model: Post,
    include: [
      { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"]},
    ],
  },
],
  }],
  }).then((user) => {
if (!user)
  return res.status(404).send();

const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

const plainUser = user.get({ plain: true });
const resultLikes = [];
for (const like of plainUser.Likes) {
  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = like;
  const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));

  resultLikes.push({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES });
}
res.send(resultLikes);

  });
 });
```

Comment: are you sure that the `like` after destructuring the object contains an array? also the resurrn value is going to be an array. Could you please provide a simple sample of what what you want to get back, what you are getting back?

Comment: (node:56344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined i am currently getting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one level of included models: `Post`.
You're trying to get Posts's props from `Like`.

```
for (const like of plainUser.Likes) {
  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = like.Post;
  const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));

  resultLikes.push({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, i just tried this solution and i got TypeError: like.Posts is not iterable

Comment: look at `like` props, maybe it should be named `Post`

Comment: which like props? Here (const like of plainUser.Likes) or here (const post of like.Posts)

Comment: `const like of plainUser.Likes`

Comment: i tried   for(const Post of plainUser.Likes){ for (const post of Post.Posts){    and still got an error Post.Posts is not iterable

Comment: It's useless to rename a variable used for iteration in `for`. Just do `console.log(like);` after `for (const like of plainUser.Likes) {`

Comment: when i do console.log(like) i get this {
  id: 78,
  PostId: 487,
  userId: 43,
  Post: {
    id: 487,
    title: 'title test',
    Post_Images: [ [Object] ],
    User: {
      id: 44,
      name: 'user',
      email: 'user@hotmail.com',
    }
  }
}

Comment: so i dont need the 2 for-loops? only 1 for loop

Comment: yep. I thought you jhave a collection of posts linked to a like

Comment: thank you,  a user can like multiple posts and a post can have multiple likes from different users does this mean that i have a collection of posts linked to a like?

Comment: i am trying it again and for some reason now when i console.log(like) i get plainUser.Likes is not iterable

Comment: add `console.log(plainUser)` before `for`

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, how do i create a isLiked query in my get request to see if userId and PostId exist in Likes table then isLiked=true otherwise false? Because in frontend i am trying to render a heart if isLiked is true and a outlined heart if isLiked is false.

Comment: It's a whole new question again

Comment: Hi @Anatoly did you manage to have a look at my other question?